# avoid class to be called from not synchronised threads

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have class that that has one function used by other classes. I have felling that my function is called from not synchronized threads. Is it good solution to add busy flags in my function to prevent calling from not synchronized threads. Will it work:

```
public class Hndl
{
boolean isBusy=false;

    public  boolean doJob()
    {
        if(!isBusy)
        {
        isBusy=true;
        ...
            return true;
        isBusy=false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you read a book on the subject of concurrent programming in Java. Your use of terminology and your proposed solution suggest you have quite a bit to learn before you are writing thread-safe code. I've voted to close this question as "too broad" as I would imagine any answer would need to go into a large amount of detail to explain the concepts.

Comment: `isBusy=false;` should be after `return true`, it will not be called in your code.

Comment: If you really need synchronized access to you method, maybe just make it synchronized? `public synchonized boolean doJob()`

Comment: *"my function is called from not synchronized threads"* Sorry this makes no sense.

Comment: The OP's code is straight from the book: "How to introduce subtle bugs in my multi-threaded Java program."

Answer (score 3):

Unless you do need to use that `busy` flag in other methods of your class, you should probably simply define your method as `synchronized` to avoid it being executed in parallel and make it `thread-safe`:

```
public synchronized boolean doJob() { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe because this sequence is possible:

```
thread 1 reads busy flag: not busy
thread 2 reads busy flag: not busy
thread 1 sets busy flag to busy
thread 2 sets busy flag to busy

both threads execute the method
```

To fix this you can use [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which requires making the flag `volatile` or it will also fail, or use a [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html):

```
Lock isBusy = new ReentrantLock();

public boolean doJob()
{
    if (isBusy.tryLock()) {
        try {
            ...
            return true;
        } finally {
            isBusy.unlock();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you make the method `synchronized` instead of using locks thread 2 would have to *wait* until thread 1 exits the method instead of returning immediately, which is not what your program attempts to do.